# Software for a DIY fibre channel SAN?

Tags: storage-area-network

I am trying to create a SAN on a budget.  This will be used with a VMware ESX 4.1 cluster for our developers to use as a sandbox/test environment.  Since this is not a production environment we do not have much budget available so we are trying to get the most bang for our buck.

Currently the environment is using an HP fibre channel storage array which is about 6-7 years old and only has 12 10k disks.  While it works fine it is quite slow because of the poor storage performance.

What we would like to do is build a storage server with 6 SSD drives in RAID 5 and make that appear to VMware as a FC storage array.  I have done this plenty of times using freenas/openfiler to present as iSCSI storage, but since we already have some 4Gb fibre switches and HBAs we would like to use them so we are not limited to 1Gbps iSCSI.

I have seen that FC target support can be compiled into the Linux kernel, but my question is if there is a simpler way to go about this (i.e. some software similar to freenas, etc that would support FC target mode "out of the box").

Comment: You mean like [LIO](http://linux-iscsi.org/wiki/LIO)? Which is already present in EL7.

Comment: Product recommendation, DIY SAN, ancient hypervisor, ancient hardware... this question needs to be nuked from orbit.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible. I know product recommendations are off-topic for this site, but several SAN appliance offerings are available for this.

These days, I recommend:

- [QuantaStor](http://www.osnexus.com) - Ubuntu-based. VMware certified. Has free and commercial variants. Uses ZFS under the hood. Excellent GUI.
- [Zetavault](http://www.dnuk.com/zetavault/intro/) - Ubuntu-based. VMware certified. Relatively inexpensive. Uses ZFS under the hood. Sparse, but functional GUI.

Don't heartily recommend the following, but it does work:

- [NexentaStor](http://www.nexenta.com/products/nexentastor) - Solaris/Illumos-based. ZFS under the hood. Release cycle is odd and community is dwindling.